# Time period in a date period

Tags: british-english, formality, time, dates, register

I want to mention the date and time I collected my questionnaires in an academic report. Let's say they are distributed:

> **Time period**: 1:00PM - 4:00PM
>
> **Date period**: 1 October 2014 - 3 October 2014

How should I write it properly in a single sentence in British English?

Comment: Collected 1.00pm-4.00pm, 1/10/2014 to 3/10/2014.

Answer (score 2):

The reports were collected over a three-day period (1st-3rd October 2014), between 1.00 and 4.00 in the afternoon on each day.